# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "dormir la mona"?

Tags: modismos, etimología, expresiones

Cuando uno ha bebido mucho alcohol, al día siguiente es típico "dormir la mona". Esto es, dormir largo y tendido para recuperar el cuerpo.

[Leo](http://www.abc.es/cultura/20140609/abci-origen-estar-todos-fregados-201406091250.html) que señalan este origen:

> «Dormir la mona», por ejemplo, se remonta al siglo XVI y que hace
>   referencia a la costumbre que había de dar vino a los monos para ver
>   el efecto que les provocaba.

Pero así y todo me parece algo raro. Es decir, la expresión se refiere a "recuperar el cuerpo" de algún modo, mientras que el origen es más de "intoxicar el cuerpo [de la mona] para ver cómo actúa".

Comment: Lo primero que me viene a la cabeza es el famoso "Anís del Mono". Curioso que "la mona" sea la borrachera y "el mono" sea el síndrome de abstinencia. Estarán relacionados?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parece ser que el origen se remonta a la práctica en fiestas de ofrecer vino a los monos para observar los efectos del alcohol.

> Ya en el siglo XVI, se empleaba la palabra “mona” para referirse a la borrachera o a la persona ebria. Se designaba al hombre borracho melancólico como “mona triste” y al borracho que baila como “mona alegre”. El origen de la expresión se remonta a la práctica en fiestas de ofrecer vino a los monos para observar los efectos del alcohol.
>
> Fuente [Estandarte: ¿Por qué se dice "dormir la mona"?](http://www.estandarte.com/noticias/idioma-espanol/por-que-se-dice-dormir-la-mona_2606.html)

Hay [otra referencia](https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/dormir-la-mona/) muy similar a la del artículo que enlazas en la pregunta. Parece ser que la comparación entre

> la conducta de un ebrio con la de un mono o una mona

El problema es que podríamos seguir aportando [otros enlaces](http://www.defensacentral.com/ustedpregunta/categoria/gramatica/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-curiosa-expresion-dormir-la-mona/) y en realidad se basan todos en la misma fuente, el libro "Con dos huevos" (ver el enlace de Estandarte)

Sin embargo, [esta web](http://www.nosabesnada.com/otras-curiosidades/69050/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-dormir-la-mona/) indica que

> En el libro de El Quijote, del siglo XVII, puede leerse «tomar la mona» como equivalente a embriagarse.

y puede que entonces sea cierto que el origen de la expresión venga porque

> simplemente, se compara la conducta de un ebrio con la de un mono o una mona, lo que tendría su lógica ya que se suele decir “hacer el mono” para describir a una persona que hace tonterías o animaladas.

Comment: Lo divertido del caso es que lo que nos ha quedado es la expresión "dormir la mona" por lo que va después de la borrachera, es decir, el reposo. En todas las referencias veo esta mención a la mona y su borrachera, pero el paso a la fase posterior es lo que aún me queda algo cojo.

Comment: @fedorqui, cierto. A mi me llama además la atención que haya pasado "mona" y no "mono", y que "mono" sea usado para el síndrome de abstinencia. Incluí en esta respuesta lo que puede encontrar en una búsqueda rápida. Si saco más tiempo volveré a intentarlo. Estoy seguro de que otros pueden aportar más y mejores datos de los que yo he incluido, o razonar mejor la evolución de la expresión. En un par de días habrá más respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Para dar más validez a [la respuesta de Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15353/12637), incluyo aquí lo que decía Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611:

> Estas monas apetecen el vino y las sopas mojadas en el, y haze diferentes efetos la borrachez en ellas, porque unas dan el alegrarse mucho y dar muchos saltos y bueltas; otras se encaporan, y se arriman a un rincon, encubriendose la cara con las manos. De aqui vino llamar mona triste al hombre borracho que està melancolico y callado, y mona alegre al que canta y bayla, y se huelga con todos.

Se ve por tanto que la fuente citada por Diego cita a su vez el *Covarrubias*. En 1734 el *Autoridades* decía lo siguiente:

> MONA. En estilo jocoso y familiar se llama la embriaguéz o borrachera. Y tambien se llama assi al que la padece ò está borracho. [...] De aqui ha nacido llamar à los borrachos *Monas*, por las descompostúras que hacen con su cuerpo.

Se entiende pues que cuando se va a *dormir la mona*, lo que se está diciendo en realidad es que "se va a dormir el borracho".

Y por dar contexto, incluyo algunos ejemplos:

> *Ya de pura lástima hice a mi maña que le sirviese de grúa y metíle en el carro, y yo tras él, tan sin miedo cuan sin tardanza y sin peligro. Reclinéle sobre las capas, sobre las cuales comenzó a dormir la mona alta y profundamente.*
>
> Francisco López de Úbeda, "La pícara Justina", 1605 (España).

Y el texto del Quijote mencionado en la respuesta de Diego:

> *—Dáselos, Sancho —dijo don Quijote—, no para tomar el mono, sino la mona; y docientos diera yo ahora en albricias a quien me dijera con certidumbre que la señora doña Melisendra y el señor don Gaiferos estaban ya en Francia y entre los suyos.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha", 1615 (España).

No encuentro por la época casos de "mona alegre" o "mona triste", debían ser expresiones coloquiales.