# ¿Por qué se llama "mono" al "síndrome de abstinencia"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, coloquialismos, animales

Coloquialmente se utiliza la palabra "mono" para designar al síndrome de abstinencia a las drogas.

¿Desde cuándo se utiliza y cómo adquirió ese significado?
Que yo recuerde, en los finales de los años 60 o principios de los 70 ya era de uso corriente.

Comment: No entendí la pregunta en un principio, pero ahora sí, y me parece buena pregunta.  Voy a aclarar un poco: Cuando un drogadicto deja de tomar su droga de repente, pasa por un periodo difícil con síntomas físicos y psicológicos (*withdrawal symptoms*).  Durante este periodo se puede decir que está pasando por el "síndrome de abstinencia", que me parece muy mal nombrado, porque ¡la persona sin adicción también practica la abstinencia, pero no sufre síntomas!  Yo preferiría *síndrome de desintoxicación*.  Pero el hecho es que así se dice.  Un sinónimo informal es "el mono".  Véase por ej. ...

Comment: ... webconsultas.com/mente-y-emociones/adicciones/…, es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Síndrome_de_abstinencia, lasdrogas.info/foro/viewtopic.php?t=2937.

Comment: ¿Podría estar relacionado con esto?: [¿De dónde viene la expresión “dormir la mona”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15351/14069)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this may be a translation from the English expression "to have a monkey on one's back" meaning having a problem which one cannot easily shake off. This is quite an old English expression. More recently, at least in my experience, it has been mostly used as a metaphor for the experience of trying to withdraw from substance abuse. Note that this is not the same as the physical experiences and symptoms of withdrawal for which we use the expression "going cold turkey", "getting the monkey off your back" is just about how difficult withdrawal is.

[This site](https://grammarist.com/idiom/monkey-on-ones-back/) states (slighthly reformatted):

> *To have a monkey on one’s back* is an idiom that has been in use for over a hundred years.
>
> ...
>
> *To have a monkey on one’s back* may be considered a metaphor that means to have a terrible burden that one can not get rid of, to grapple with a problem that will not go away.
>
> **Often, *to have a monkey on one’s back* means to have an addiction that one cannot control, or to be addicted to drugs, or suffering withdrawal from a drug addiction.**
>
> The origin of this idiom may be the stories of Sinbad; the earliest known Sinbad works are from the seventeenth century. In one story, a creature described somewhat like an ape jumps on Sinbad’s back and will not get off. However, an older story attributed to Aesop involves a dolphin giving a monkey a ride through the water.
>
> The idioms *monkey on the roof* and *monkey up the chimney* meant one had a mortgage to pay, in the late 1800s. *Having a monkey on one’s back* in the 1800s meant to be angry.
>
> Later, having a monkey on one’s back came to mean having a terrible burden. **In the 1930s the idiom was applied to a drug addiction, particularly heroin.**

Answer (score 3):

Es una pregunta interesante, así que lamento dar solamente una respuesta parcial y tentativa.

Por lo que he estado leyendo en la hemeroteca, a finales de la década de 1970 la prensa todavía sentía la necesidad de explicar lo que era el "mono":

> *La falta de la droga produce el síndrome de abstinencia y lo que los adictos españoles llaman «mono» [...].* (Cambio 16, 1979.)
>
> *Lo único que se sabe es que estaba atravesando el «mono» (síndrome de abstinencia provocado por la falta de una droga) [...].* (ABC, 1980.)

Por el primer ejemplo se sabe que durante la década de 1970 ya se usaba el término de forma oral entre los drogadictos. Pero ¿por qué *mono*? La única pista que he encontrado es que a principios de la década de 1970 ya eran habituales los ensayos clínicos con monos para estudiar el síndrome de abstinencia:

> *«Nuestras investigaciones nos han conducido al descubrimiento de que en los monos puede abolirse el «craving» o deseo imperioso hacia la morfina, y también a reducir al mínimo el síndrome de la abstinencia después de su uso», han manifestado los doctores [...].* (ABC, 1972.)

En este ejemplo resulta llamativo el uso de *craving* para denominar lo que hoy conocemos como "antojo" ("tener mono de algo", pero en un sentido ajeno a las drogas, como en "tengo mono de helado"), lo que hace suponer que la voz *mono* aún no había adquirido ese sentido de "síndrome de abstinencia", o bien se estaba formando y apenas se conocía (a fin de cuentas, la pregunta afirma que a principios de los 70 ya se usaba).

Hasta aquí respondería a tu primera pregunta. Sobre la segunda, mi suposición es que las noticias de estos estudios del síndrome de abstinencia en monos pudieron causar que se llamara *mono* a dicho síndrome. La lástima es que no tengo pruebas de ello, pero me parece demasiada casualidad que en 1972 se hable de *craving* y a finales de la década, tras años de publicar noticias similares (encuentro una noticia similar en 1976), a finales de la década ya se hable de "tener el mono".

Por otro lado, [según comenta mdewey](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31133/por-qu%c3%a9-se-llama-mono-al-s%c3%adndrome-de-abstinencia/31137?noredirect=1#comment53824_31137) existe una expresión en inglés, *to have a monkey on one's back*, que se usa para cuando tienes una carga de la que no te puedes librar, incluyendo una adicción a una droga. Para mí tendría mucho más sentido que se adaptara esa expresión al español y así sugiese *el mono*. Espero que mdewey nos pueda ampliar esto.

Comment: I did not post because the question is in Spanish but you might want to look at the English expression monkey on one's back. This is used, for instance, in the phrase getting the monkey off one's back referring to trying to withdraw from substance abuse.

Comment: @mdewey it makes much more sense for the Spanish expression to be a translation of the English one. I agree with saki that you could add that as an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: @saki I have not included all of your comment in my answer but perhaps it should be there in case the comments disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Usualmente el 'pack' de síntomas de abstinencia (hablando de drogas duras: estimulantes u opiáceos) suele ser: irritabilidad, malestar y/o dolor físico, espasmos (mandíbula, cuello), mareos, nauseas, comezón, dolor de cabeza (entre muchos otros).
Ahora imaginate a alguien rascándose, completamente irritado e incómodo, sin poder controlar (al menos la mayoría) sus espasmos: el resultado es la mímica de 'un mono'.